# Retail-rendered deform Form (using form attribute) - processing of date is unreliable

Tags: python, http-post, pyramid, deform

Quick summary: How do I ensure correct order of values in request.POST?

I'm using a HTML table (augmented using DataTables to hide columns etc, with the only effect of that being that hidden columns are not included in the call to 'submit') and rendering one deform Form per row.

As deform [does not directly support split forms using the form attribute](https://github.com/Pylons/deform/issues/335) I manually insert `form=my_desired_unique_id` into all relevant elements. This works fine for simple elements like `<input>` and `<textarea>`, the values show up in `request.POST.items()` and validate fine.

For the deform date-picker things are a bit more complicated though. `form['datecolumn'].serialize` will generate something like this:-

```
<input type="hidden" name="__start__" value="datecolumn:mapping"/>
<input type="date"
       name="date"
       value="2017-01-01"
       id="deformField6" class="  form-control hasDatepicker"/>
<input type="hidden" name="__end__" value="datecolumn:mapping"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
 deform.addCallback(
  'deformField6',
   function deform_cb(oid) {
     if (!Modernizr.inputtypes['date'] ||"date" != "date" || window.forceDateTimePolyfill){
       $('#' + oid).pickadate({"format": "yyyy-mm-dd", "selectMonths": true, "selectYears": true, "formatSubmit": "yyyy-mm-dd"});
     }
   }
 );
</script>
```

There's 3 inputs there (and a fourth hidden one gets added in the rendered HTML with the name 'date_submit'). The visible input's value does not change when the user selects a new date, but the new hidden one's does. On a submit, somehow that value is passed on to the main 'date' input (some js which I don't have a handle on).

The resulting `request.POST.items()` contains these three elements from the date input:-

1. `('__start__', 'datecolumn:mapping')`
2. `('date', '2017-02-24')` (this is the newly selected date)
3. `('__end__', 'datecolumn:mapping')`

My issue here is that the order of these values is unreliable. On the same page and form, clicking submit multiple times will result in different orders of values in `request.POST.items()` (all values, not just the date related ones). If the resulting order is as above, things work fine, but if the order is different (say end is before start, or date is after or before both) then I either get a ValueError raised or a validation failure.

I could possibly iterate through `request.POST.items()` first and ensure the right arrangement, but I want two date pickers in this form, and I have no way of knowing which `date` field belongs to which pair of `__start__` and `__end__` markers.

Is there any way to control the order of elements in a POST before it's sent to my view code?

Answer (score 0):

The hack I came up with (will accept any better answers that this!) involves two parts.

1. Tag each date element (I name all my date elements as *_date) uniquely in my template.
2. Use the template to re-generate the appropriate POST items.

Specifically, for step one I generate the serialized widget using this function:-

```
def serialize_with_formid(form, elem_name, formid):
    retval = form[elem_name].serialize()
    retval = retval.replace('<input type=', '<input form={} type='.format(formid))
    retval = retval.replace('<textarea', '<textarea form={}'.format(formid))
    if elem_name.endswith('date'):  # 'Mark' datepick elements appropriately
        retval = retval.replace('name="date"', 'name="{}"'.format(elem_name))
    return retval
```

The `form` is the created form instance, `elem_name` ends with 'date' for datepicker elements, and `formid` is unique to each form on the page (of which there are many in my page). Lines 2 and 3 insert `formid` where appropriate, and the `if` marks datepicker elements.

For step 2 I first remove all `__start__` and `__end__` elements from `request.POST`, then find the elements in `request.POST` which end with `date` and use them to append (in the right order) elements to `request.POST`.

```
def fix_broken_POST(request):
    '''
    For some reason I'm getting POST elements out of order with retail rendered
    form-attribute reliant forms. This reorders the crucial elements (date-related)
    so that deform can then do validation etc.
    '''
    while True:
        try:  # Assumes same number of both
            request.POST.pop('__start__')
            request.POST.pop('__end__')
        except KeyError as e:
            break
    list_of_date_keys = [i for i in request.POST.keys() if i.endswith('date')]
    list_of_tuples = []
    for key in list_of_date_keys:
        value = request.POST.pop(key)
        list_of_tuples.append(('__start__', '{}:mapping'.format(key)))
        list_of_tuples.append(('date', value))
        list_of_tuples.append(('__end__', '{}:mapping'.format(key)))
    request.POST.extend(list_of_tuples)
```

Again, this is obviously a hack/workaround, so something a bit more... elegant would be appreciated.